# Angular 2 Select - Load data from web service trouble

Tags: angular, jquery-chosen, jquery-select2, ng2-bootstrap

I am using [ng2-select](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select) to display a list of items so that user can search and find the appropriate one from select list. The problem I am facing is that it only works on static data. My data is loaded from RESTful webservice. I have tried multiple hacks and tricks but I am unable to load data from web service into ng2-select. It appears that this plugin does not support loading web service data. 
Is there a working hack to load webservice data into ng2-select ?

If not please suggest an other angular2 plugin which can load data from web service and enables user to search and select.

**Update :**

I missed to mention that i am successfully getting data from my web service. There is no issue in getting data from web service. The problem is with ng2-select. I successfully populate the `items` array with the fetched data from web service(confirmed by printed items array on console) but ng2-select does not show anything. If I do not fetch data from web service and only populate the array with local data(which is assigned at the time of initializing), it works and displays local data.
**It Just cant seem to work with requests. Here is an example code from a comment**

**Product-Category.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class ProductCategoryService
{
    apiUrl: string = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    constructor(private http : Http){}
    public getUserData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
            .map(result => {
                return result.json();
            });
    }
}
```

**Product-category.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit , ViewChild , AfterViewInit , ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers , Response , RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'product-category',
    templateUrl: 'product-category.component.html',
    styles: []
})
export class AddProductCategoryComponent implements OnInit
{
    public items = [];
    my :boolean= false;
    constructor(public productCategoryService:ProductCategoryService){}
    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.getItems();
    }
    getItems()
    {
        this.productCategoryService.getUserData().subscribe(
            items => this.items
    );
    }
```

**Update2:**
For simplicity i have attached a code and an image to better understand. You can see in the code and image that after getting a response back from the server. The result can be seen in the console. But for simplicity lets add an entry in the array manually. You can see that `ng2-select` only displays the data which was populated before sending the request, but the array also contains the object which was populated after getting response back from the server.

**Code**

```
public items: any = [];
ngOnInit()
    {
        this.items.push({id : 1 , text : 'Option1'});
        this.getItems();
        console.log(this.items);
    }
    getItems()
    {
        this.productCategoryService.getUserData().subscribe(
            success =>
            {
                this.items.push({id : 2 , text : 'Option2'});
                console.log(success);
            }
    );
    }
```

**Image**
[image: ng2-select]

Comment: could you add the code

Comment: Please take a look at the code

Answer (score 1):

for that you can create service which fetches data from your server

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  apiUrl: string = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }


  //getUserData(): Observable<any> {

    //return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
    //  .map(result => {
    //    return result.json();
    //  });
  //}
  // just for testing use this mechanisum if it working for you or not
  getUserData(): Promise<any[]> {
      return Promise.resolve(ITEMS);
  } 


}

public ITEMS:Array<string> = ['Amsterdam', 'Antwerp', 'Athens', 'Barcelona',
'Berlin', 'Birmingham', 'Bradford', 'Bremen', 'Brussels', 'Bucharest',
'Budapest', 'Cologne', 'Copenhagen', 'Dortmund', 'Dresden', 'Dublin',
'Düsseldorf', 'Essen', 'Frankfurt', 'Genoa', 'Glasgow', 'Gothenburg',
'Hamburg', 'Hannover', 'Helsinki', 'Kraków', 'Leeds', 'Leipzig', 'Lisbon',
'London', 'Madrid', 'Manchester', 'Marseille', 'Milan', 'Munich', 'Málaga',
'Naples', 'Palermo', 'Paris', 'Poznań', 'Prague', 'Riga', 'Rome',
'Rotterdam', 'Seville', 'Sheffield', 'Sofia', 'Stockholm', 'Stuttgart',
'The Hague', 'Turin', 'Valencia', 'Vienna', 'Vilnius', 'Warsaw', 'Wrocław',
'Zagreb', 'Zaragoza', 'Łódź'];
```

try this code and you will get 10 users data. this is the basic way, you can call any GET api in Angular 2.

add this service to **@NgModule in ap.module.ts** file:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [UserService]
})
```

than call that service in Component class like this:

```
items = [];


constructor(private userService: UserService){}

onNgInit(){
   this.getItems();
}

getItems() {
    //this.userService.getUserData().subscribe(
    //   items => this.items;
    //);
    this.userService.getUserData().then(results=> this.items = results);
}



<ng-select [allowClear]="true"
              [items]="items" // here that items will come, but it will be object, i hope in your service you will get Array[] items.
              [disabled]="disabled"
              (data)="refreshValue($event)"
              (selected)="selected($event)"
              (removed)="removed($event)"
              (typed)="typed($event)"
              placeholder="No city selected">
  </ng-select>
```

Comment: There was no problem in getting data from web service. I still tested your code and ng2-select is not showing anything now.

Comment: can you plz show your code and data so i can look at that

Comment: Thank you for your continuous support @Vinay. I have added image and code. Hope it helps.

Comment: have replaced this url http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users in my code with your api url? bcz this url give you different kind of data which is not supported with ng2-select.

Comment: are you using AdminLTE with angular 2?, can you share where did you find that?